# Ensure one app runs in full screen; prioritize the other for higher resources due to increased usage

Tags: windows-10

I have two applications ( 1.UI and 2. C++ app ) running which are interdependent. The UI is in full screen mode and the C++ app is running minimzed or in background. The C++ application doesn't need to be in fullscreen mode and uses more resources.

I want the C++ application to have more priority than the UI in terms of using resources.

Changing the priorty in task manager. Making the UI to low priority and C++ application to high priority doesn't work.

Using the function SetPriorityClass:HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS in C++ application also doesn't work.